# Open navigation drawer when options menu button is pressed

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-support-library, navigation-drawer

I'd like the navigation drawer opened when the *options menu* button is pressed. So in my Sherlock Fragment activity I added:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerLinear)) {
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerLinear);
    }
    return true;
}
```

For some reason nothing happens when the options menu button is pressed.

Otherwise the drawer is working fine. It opens when the app icon on the action bar is pressed or when I pull it.
So what's wrong?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Maybe your referring to [onKeyDown (int keyCode, KeyEvent event)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onKeyDown%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29)

sample:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent e) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
        // your action...

        if (!mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerLinear)) {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerLinear);
        }
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, e);
}
```

Comment: You should probably return true as well. From the docs `If you handled the event, return true. If you want to allow the event to be handled by the next receiver, return false.`

Answer (score 11):

The answer above is good, I just want to add some clarification (open/close version):

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {

        View drawerView = findViewById(R.id.navigation_drawer); // child drawer view

        if (!mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(drawerView)) {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(drawerView);
        } else if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(drawerView)) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerView);
        }
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Where `mDrawerLayout` is the parent activity layout and `drawerView` the child view for the drawer inside the activity layout (list or smth.)