# open navigation drawer when options icon pressed

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-button

I use navigation drawer in my app, set from right to left. I want it to only open when I press the options menu button is pressed(3 dots).

I tried this thread 
[Open navigation drawer when options menu button is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20842849/open-navigation-drawer-when-options-menu-button-is-pressed) 
but not working.

menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Comment: mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(your view);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are pressing the 3 dots android will reveal the menu items that are collapsed.
If you want to open the drawer from a menu item, I suggest you find an icon representing the 3 dots (or keep the drawer like icon) and:

Menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/ic_options"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_dots"
        android:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

Code

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.ic_options:
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(your view);
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Surrender Kumar said, you have to open the drawer manually but from onOptionsItemSelected

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_settings:
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(your view);
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

You need to put showAsAction=ifRoom on your menu and an icon:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

Comment: No,this is not I meant. By this method pressing the 3 dots, menu opens and in the menu when settings is pressed the drawer shows. I want to open the drawer when I press the 3 dots.

Comment: Have you tried the last modification (showAsAction=ifRoom) ?